# .NET navigate not working?

Tags: .net, vb.net, navigateurl

I have a separate form with a WebBrowser control. The script won't run if I try to invoke it from another form but it does run if I invoke it in the same form.

```
Dim JS As New jsEncrypt

    JS.WebBrowser.Navigate(New Uri(Environment.CurrentDirectory() & "\web\javascript.html"))

    Dim str As String = JS.WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eisu")
    Application.Run(JS)

    Console.WriteLine(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Run(...)` doesn't return immediately.  Try your `Navigate` step before `Application.Run()`.

Comment: ok, it loads the page but now it won't run my script

      

        Dim str As String = JS.WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eisu")